# Google fit REST API Cannot add some of the data source

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am trying to add a specific datasource and the scopes are

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write
```

But when I try to do so. It returns me an error of

```
      {
        "reason": "invalidArgument", 
        "message": "Data type does not match well-known data type with the same name", 
        "domain": "global"
      }
```

I send POST request to this URL
`https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources`

Here is my request body

```
{
  "dataStreamName": "MyDataSource",
  "type": "derived",
  "application": {
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com",
    "name": "Foo Example App",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "activty_type",
        "format": "integer"
      }
    ],
    "name": "com.google.activity.segment"
  },
  "device": {
    "manufacturer": "Example Manufacturer",
    "model": "ExampleTablet",
    "type": "tablet",
    "uid": "1000001",
    "version": "1.0"
  }
}
```

I am using PHP/Laravel as a language and I use CURL as an http request library. Can someone tell me what did I do wrong? Some of the scopes are successfully added but there are others that cannot be added.

Google docs reference: https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/activity?authuser=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, activity_type (which you have a typo in) isn't the correct string. `com.google.activity.segment` requires `activity` field.

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types?authuser=3).

So this would, as it returns expected resource and HTTP 200 in the Google Fit API Testing Console, work:

```
{
  "dataStreamName": "MyDataSource",
  "type": "derived",
  "application": {
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com",
    "name": "Foo Example App",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "dataType": {
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "activity",
        "format": "integer"
      }
    ],
    "name": "com.google.activity.segment"
  },
  "device": {
    "manufacturer": "Example Manufacturer",
    "model": "ExampleTablet",
    "type": "tablet",
    "uid": "1000001",
    "version": "1.0"
  }
}
```